# TimeZone configurations

Tags: android, timezone

i receive this string in my **SimpleDateFormat** "Sun, 02 Oct 2011 14:00:00 +0100", it's possible to decrease 1 hour in my output? Instead of +0100 have GMT?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the actual time (i.e. time = time - 1hr), or do you just want to print the time in GMT time ?

Comment: Can you teach me the both ways? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an hour off:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
sf.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
Date now = calendar.getTime();

calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR,-1);
Date earlierTime = calendar.getTime();
System.out.println(sf.format(now)); // output: Thu, 06 Oct 2011 11:53:58 GMT
System.out.println(sf.format(earlierTime)); // output: Thu, 06 Oct 2011 10:53:58 GMT
```